# How to show that the configuration space of two beads on a rod is a triangle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I do math, and this problem showed up in the setting of translation surfaces.

Lets say we have two beads of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ on a rod of length $a$, with $m_1$ on the left of $m_2$. Denote their positions $x_1, x_2$, and rescaling them $\tilde{x_i} = \sqrt{m_i} x_i$.

How to show that the configuration space is a triangle $\Delta$ with sides $\tilde{x_1} = 0$, $\tilde{x_2} = \sqrt{m_2} a$, and $\tilde{x_2} = \sqrt{\frac{m_2}{m_1}}$, and the trajectories of the two beads on the rod corresponding to billiard trajectories in the triangle $\Delta$?

Here is what I have tried doing: Given a "mirror" in the direction of the normalized vector $e$, and normal $n$ on the reflective side, reflection of the velocity vector $v_e e + v_n n$ happens based on the law $$R(v_e e + v_n n) = v_e e - v_n n.$$

Now, the two balls change their trajectory when they collide with one of the walls, or each other. Conservation of momentum immediately implies that when they hit the walls, their trajectories "reflect" off the sides $\tilde{x_1} = 0$ and $\tilde{x_2} = \sqrt{m_2} a$. What I am having trouble with is when they collide with each other.

If we denote $v = (d\tilde{x_1} / dt, d\tilde{x_2} / dt)$, conservation of momentum immediately implies $v_e^\prime = v_e$. How can I show that $v_n^\prime = - v_n$?

Comment: I can't visualize your problem. Can you add a diagram? In particular the description of the sides makes no sense to me - is it possible you have a typo?

Comment: @Floris I guess the third side must be $\tilde x_2 = \sqrt{m_2\over m_1}x_1$